# How to get customAPI url from node.js app?

Tags: integration, ibm-cloud

I am just starting with BlueMix and in my space I have:

- a Cloud Integration service: using a Basic Secure Connection, for which I have created an API endpoint; then in that Cloud Integration service I have added the corresponding API by importing a swagger 1.2 file, and published that customAPI to my organization;
- a pretty simple node.js application;

From the Cloud Integration service> API view, I can get the URLs for the different resources (for instance `http://endpoint_ip:endpoint_port/api/version/path_to_resource`), so I can hardcode these URLs in my node.js application and it works. 

But if I bind the Cloud Integration service and even the customAPI to my node.js application, I don't get any information in VCAP_SERVICES about the endpoint URL; but I have seen examples of VCAP_SERVICES where the API URL is available.

Below is my VCAP_SERVICES

```
{"CloudIntegration": [
      {
         "name": "Cloud Integration-b9",
         "label": "CloudIntegration",
         "plan": "cloudintegrationplan",
         "credentials": {
            "userid": "apiuser@CloudIntegration",
            "password": "S!2w3e40",
            "apis": [
               {
                  "name": "Catalog Manager API",
                  "desc": "Catalog Manager API",
                  "resource": ""
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to avoid hardcoding URLs in my application, since I can bind a BlueMix service to it, and perhaps get info from the environment.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is that not the way it is supposed to work?
Also I don't really get why there is nothing in the `VCAP_SERVICES.CloudIntegration[0].credentials.apis[0].resource` even though I have my customAPI specifies resources.

Comment: Did you restart your application? The VCAP_SERVICES change won't be reflected without a restart or restage.

Comment: @Jack-Junjie Cai: Yes, I restarted the application. In fact each time I add/bind a new service, it asks me to restart/restage the application

Answer (score 0):

@Rick

Make sure you "publish" your API after configuring the Cloud Integration service. Then service credentials will reflect the changes:

```
"CloudIntegration": [
  {
     "name": "Cloud Integration-v5",
     "label": "CloudIntegration",
     "plan": "cloudintegrationplan",
     "credentials": {
        "userid": "apiuser@CloudIntegration",
        "password": "S!2w3e40",
        "apis": [
           {
              "name": "SwaggerPetStore",
              "desc": "SwaggerPetStore",
              "resource": "http",
              "baseurl": "http://mypypatchank.mybluemix.net"
           }
        ]
     }
  }
]
```

in the same way, if you use the API management service, you will have a corresponding VCAP_SERVICES entry

```
"Swagger Petstore v1 : Sandbox 551b2dcf0cf2521d98d061d4 prod": [
  {
     "name": "Swagger Petstore v1 : Sandbox prod-w0",
     "label": "Swagger Petstore v1 : Sandbox 551b2dcf0cf2521d98d061d4 prod",
     "plan": "plan1 : Sandbox prod",
     "credentials": {
        "clientID": "55cfe3fa-ff59-474c-a1b6-46d3cc9871",
        "clientSecret": "uK3xM3eF4cA1qF7yW8mC2lP6wS6aG7sQ5cL2yJ4sC6iS1dE7",
        "url": "https://api.eu.apim.ibmcloud.com/garciatemx1ibmcom/sb/api"
     }
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, I have published my API but my resource/baseurl didn't change (still empty). Could it be that my swagger file is missing some information ? Or do I have to go through API Management to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to "to avoid hardcoding URLs in my application, since I can bind a BlueMix service to it, and perhaps get info from the environment." I would like to suggest using a user provided service.

This will create a user provided service and start interactive input for you to enter the api url and a password. You can add more parameters if you need.

`cf cups servicename -p "url, password"`

Bind this service to your application and restage. You can access these parameters in your Node.js application easily with the `cfenv` module.

```
var cfenv = require("cfenv");
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();
var myService = appEnv.getService("servicename");

//use myService.credentials.url to access the url value.
//use myService.credentials.password to access the password value.
```

The user provided services VCAP_SERVICES looks like:

```
{
  "user-provided": [
    {
      "name": "servicename",
      "label": "user-provided",
      "credentials": {
        "url": "myURL",
        "password": "myPassword"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```